# Float dropdown elements push each other to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a project where there are multiple dropdowns on one page. To get these dropdowns in order I use float left, the problem is that when I open one of the dropdowns on the left it pushes some of them to the right. What needs to happen is that the dropdowns underneath the open dropdown need to move down, and not to the other side.

I have tried to use "clear: both" and "Overflow: auto", but these didn't work.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p85ga09f/

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.accordion_holder {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #eaeaea;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1%;
}

.accordion {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

li {
  line-height: 28px;
}

i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

li,
a {
  color: #FF4212;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="accordion_holder">
    <button class="accordion">
      Placeholder 1
    </button>
    <div class="panel">
      <ul>
        <a href="#" target="_parent">
          <li>test</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#" target="_parent">
          <li>tset</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_holder">
    <button class="accordion">
      Placeholder 2
    </button>
    <div class="panel">
      <ul>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_holder">
    <button class="accordion">
      Placeholder 3
    </button>
    <div class="panel">
      <ul>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The dropdowns need to stay on their rows and columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr03tjvq/5/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the problem is that I want the other dropdowns to move down according to the height of the open dropdown.

Comment: @Satif If you have an answer, write it as an answer not as a comment, and explain it. It is useful for Kjvhout and for who will have the same problem.

Comment: It's important to know if you're setting things dynamically. You could either use `clear` on the correct element - which simply solves the problem (https://jsfiddle.net/vzmdkrtc/) - or you could use `flexbox`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work

Comment: `.accordion_holder:nth-child(2n+1) { clear:left; }` to be a bit more flexible for a variable number of elements. If you don’t always let two of those elements float next to each other though, you might need to modify that number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using "clear: left" on the left accordion button of each row should solve your problem.
So adding a class to Placeholder 3 with "clear: left" worked in my case.

Edit: As others have suggested; this is a quick fix that should work if you only have a few buttons. For larger accordions, I'd advise using a Flexbox or Grid instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just using flexbox should work - add

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

to the 'content' container and it should display the way you want:
https://jsfiddle.net/p8e0najc/

Comment: thank you! flex box is great for this. if you want them straight up and down, you'll need to "flex-direction: column;"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using flexbox instead of float is an option? You have way more control over how items behave next to each other. A guide I like to use is https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

You can reach this approach with using css grids, for example:

```
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fmn827ga/3/

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments. It is crucial to know if you're handling a dynamical list or if you know the amount of elements that you'll render.

If you want to use a more generic way, you should use Flexbox. Thus, you can dynamically add as many elements as you want and still keep the same functionality.

However, if you want a quick (and also dirty) fix for your problem and keep your current solution, you could also specify which elements you want to push down. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vzmdkrtc/).

According to the fiddle you just have to set the `clear: left` on the correct element which actually is the 3rd one. To be more flexible (thanks to @04FS) you could also use a class definition like this:

```
.accordion_holder:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to show like this. You can make this using flex box.
https://jsfiddle.net/b8s1y629/1/

```
            .content{
              display:flex;
              flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
```

Comment: Please add a bit more verbose explanation. Keep the code example short. Styling rules not crucial for answering the questions should be left out for readability.